Is there a limit to the number of “Blood Avengers”?
According to Rabbi Akiva from the Gemara in Makkot 11a who only permits the blood avenger (Goel Hadam) to kill the one who killed accidentally (and does not permit anyone else to), is there a limit as to how many of these blood avengers can pursue the killer? For example, a family of 12 siblings, can they all go after the person or do they need to appoint one person?
I’ve heard many svaras that there is no limit but haven’t seen any source, if anyone has any I would appreciate it
Thank you
